# Spring WebSockets exception when using Spring 4.0.3.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

I have the following web socket configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    private static final long heartbeatTime =  60000L; // 1 minute

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint(Constants.BASE_NOTI).withSockJS().setInterceptors(new HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor()).setHeartbeatTime(heartbeatTime).setSessionCookieNeeded(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        .....
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.taskExecutor().corePoolSize(2).maxPoolSize(3);
    }

     @Override
     public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
            registration.setMessageSizeLimit(128 * 1024).setSendTimeLimit(15 * 1000).setSendBufferSizeLimit(512 * 1024);
     }
}
```

The exception which i see from time to time is

```
ERROR] org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator - Transport error for SockJS session id=le1yrwx7
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:243)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.sendCloseMessage(WsSession.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.onClose(WsSession.java:440)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataControl(WsFrameBase.java:324)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:270)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:54)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler$WsReadListener.onDataAvailable(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:194)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.onDataAvailable(AbstractServletInputStream.java:189)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractProcessor.upgradeDispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:92)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:605)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.FutureToSendHandler.get(FutureToSendHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:238)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.BioServletOutputStream.doWrite(BioServletOutputStream.java:37)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletOutputStream.writeInternal(AbstractServletOutputStream.java:125)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletOutputStream.write(AbstractServletOutputStream.java:92)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.onWritePossible(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:94)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.doWrite(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.writeMessagePart(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:378)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessage(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:279)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:233)
    ... 14 more
```

after updating to nio connector i still receive the following exceptions

```
[ERROR] org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator - Transport error for SockJsSession[id=g4v7irfv, state=OPEN, sinceCreated=12010, sinceLastActive=12010]
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendPartialString(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:219)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendPartialString(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:185)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointBasic.sendText(WsRemoteEndpointBasic.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketSession.sendTextMessage(StandardWebSocketSession.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.AbstractWebSocketSession.sendMessage(AbstractWebSocketSession.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.WebSocketServerSockJsSession.initializeDelegateSession(WebSocketServerSockJsSession.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.SockJsWebSocketHandler.afterConnectionEstablished(SockJsWebSocketHandler.java:72)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.onOpen(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:101)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.init(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:633)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1720)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.FutureToSendHandler.get(FutureToSendHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendPartialString(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:214)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:185)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.NioServletOutputStream.doWriteInternal(NioServletOutputStream.java:93)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.NioServletOutputStream.doWrite(NioServletOutputStream.java:60)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletOutputStream.writeInternal(AbstractServletOutputStream.java:125)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletOutputStream.write(AbstractServletOutputStream.java:92)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.onWritePossible(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:94)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.doWrite(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.writeMessagePart(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:393)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessage(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:287)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase$TextMessageSendHandler.write(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:687)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendPartialString(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:210)
    ... 15 more
[WARN] org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.WebSocketServerSockJsSession - Failed to send SockJS close frame: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Key must be cancelled
[ERROR] org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator - Transport error for SockJsSession[id=g4v7irfv, state=CLOSED, sinceCreated=12020, sinceLastActive=0]
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Key must be cancelled
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:243)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.sendCloseMessage(WsSession.java:487)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.doClose(WsSession.java:418)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.close(WsSession.java:395)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketSession.closeInternal(StandardWebSocketSession.java:217)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.AbstractWebSocketSession.close(AbstractWebSocketSession.java:139)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.WebSocketServerSockJsSession.disconnect(WebSocketServerSockJsSession.java:229)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.close(AbstractSockJsSession.java:290)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.tryCloseWithSockJsTransportError(AbstractSockJsSession.java:321)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.WebSocketServerSockJsSession.initializeDelegateSession(WebSocketServerSockJsSession.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.SockJsWebSocketHandler.afterConnectionEstablished(SockJsWebSocketHandler.java:72)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.onOpen(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:101)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.init(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:633)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1720)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Key must be cancelled
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.FutureToSendHandler.get(FutureToSendHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:238)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Key must be cancelled
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.NioServletOutputStream.doWriteInternal(NioServletOutputStream.java:83)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.NioServletOutputStream.doWrite(NioServletOutputStream.java:60)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletOutputStream.writeInternal(AbstractServletOutputStream.java:125)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletOutputStream.write(AbstractServletOutputStream.java:92)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.onWritePossible(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:94)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.doWrite(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.writeMessagePart(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:393)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessage(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:287)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:233)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator - Transport error for SockJsSession[id=g4v7irfv, state=CLOSED, sinceCreated=12031, sinceLastActive=11]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureReadOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:252)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:295)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.read(NioChannel.java:136)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.NioServletInputStream.fillReadBuffer(NioServletInputStream.java:136)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.NioServletInputStream.doRead(NioServletInputStream.java:80)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.read(AbstractServletInputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:45)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler$WsReadListener.onDataAvailable(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:194)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.onDataAvailable(AbstractServletInputStream.java:189)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractProcessor.upgradeDispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:92)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:605)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1720)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from this `Software caused connection abort: socket write error`, it looks like the server is trying to write to the socket but the connection is already closed.

Some reasons I can think of:

- the client closed the connection willingly (by hitting the "stop" button in the browser, or closing the browser alltogether)
- some network issue happened and the connection got closed
- a timeout expired somewhere

For this case at least, this happens during the HTTP upgrade phase, which leads me to ask: do you have browser network/console logs for these cases? Maybe the client does not support the HTTP upgrade and closes the connection?

In any case, I strongly suggest you to [configure your Tomcat server to use the NIO connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html#Production_usage).

Comment: Yes i am using 4.0.3. What it is not resolved yet...:)

Comment: updated my answer - I misread the stacktrace at first, this is in fact not related to the issue I previously mentionned.

Comment: i realized it's the first time when i login to my home page the exception is thrown

Comment: @Brain Clozel i am using now nio connector but still there are exceptions... updated and posted new exceptions...